# r - make plotting function with ggplot2, aes_string and reorder

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to make a function that will use `ggplot2`inside,`aes_string`and `reorder` but with no luck so far.

Basically if we have a sample dataset like the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
dt <- data.frame(
          id = c(1,1,1,2,2),
          a = c("b", "d", "c", "a", "b"),
          b = sample(1:10, 5, replace = F),
          cat = c(1,1,2,2,2)) %>%
    mutate(a = as.factor(a)) %>% 
    as_tibble()
```

I want the function to accept the following arguments: the dataset, a filtering variable, and two variables for plotting.

This is what I managed to do:

```
myplot <- function(df, filtval, var1, var2) {
    data <- df %>% filter(id == filtval)

    ggplot(data) + 
        geom_point(
            aes_string(
                x = reorder(var1, var2),
                y = var2)
    )
}
```

Unfortunately when running it returns the error:

```
myplot(dt, 1, "a", "b")
Warning message:
    In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

This is what I want the function to do:

```
data <- dt %>% filter(id == 1)
ggplot(data) + 
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(a, - b), y = b))
```

Comment: Your problem is with reorder, what are you trying to do with `reorder(var1, var2)`?

Comment: I want to reorder the points from biggest to smallest according to the y variable

Comment: FYI, `aes_string` is being deprecated in favor of non-standard evaluation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest version of ggplot, you should be use `aes` with `!!` and `sym()` to turn your strings into symbols.

```
myplot <- function(df, filtval, var1, var2) {
  data <- df %>% filter(id == filtval)

  ggplot(data) + 
    geom_point(
      aes(
        x = reorder(!!sym(var1), !!sym(var2)),
        y = !!sym(var2))
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right but I think it's not a good idea to "mix" ggplot with functions that modify the inputs (such as reorder)... Better separate the different steps as it is clearer what each part of the code is doing.

Comment: But reordering is purely a visual preference. There's no reason you need to update your data just for the plot. Creating some other random column doesn't make much sense to me. But really both ways work so it's a personal preference. Plus Hadley has declared the intention to [deprecate `aes_string` in the long run](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/).

Comment: Well, you know what... I think you might be right :) Just a question why not using `get(X)` instead of `!!sym(X)`?

Comment: With `!!sym()` the correct variable name will be expanded into things like axes labels. Plus, it's just the recommended way to avoid the delayed lookup later.

Comment: thanks, very instructive, I recommended your answer.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing with mr Flick (see below), this should do NOT be used:

```
myplot <- function(df, filtval, var1, var2) {
  data <- df %>% filter(id == filtval)
  data$new_order <- reorder(data[[var1]], data[[var2]])

  ggplot(data) + 
    geom_point(mapping=
      aes_string(
        x = "new_order",
        y = var2)
    )
}
```

Take his solution instead :)